# Make PyTorch variables to float64

Tags: python, pytorch

How to make all the variables created in a PyTorch file to float64? 
Is there a single line of code which can do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default tensor type using this one-liner:

```
torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.DoubleTensor)
```

Comment: Then everything is float32 not float64. Does it depend on device ?

Comment: @RISHITHEM That's surprising... By default Double means 64 bit, not 32. And according to https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html, DoubleTensor should be 64-bit. On my current machine, I get `64` on all devices (2080ti gpus).